# Setting the 'is_in_stock' for product in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to write a script to set changes to 'is_in_stock' for products SKU in Magento using php/mage.

This is what I have so far, in Magento  1.9.2.1

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app();
set_time_limit(0);

$inStock = array('NOTAVAILABLE'=>'0','AVAILABLE'=>'1');
$updated=0;

$SKU = '801647';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$SKU);

if ($product) {
    //Product found, so we need to update it in Magento.

    $productId = $product->getId();
    $stockItem =Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
    $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();

    echo "is_in_stock before: ",$stockItem->getIsInStock()," <br />";


    if((int) $stockItem->getIsInStock() !== (int) $inStock["NOTAVAILABLE"]){
        try {

            $stockItem->setStockData('is_in_stock', (int) $inStock["NOTAVAILABLE"]);

            $stockItem->save();
            $product->save();
            $updated++;

            echo "SKU: '",$SKU,"' <br /> Name: '",(string) $product->name,"', <br />is_in_stock after: ",$stockItem->getIsInStock()," <br />";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
 is_in_stock before: 1 

 Product: 
 SKU: '801647' 
 Name: 'BAMBOLA PIPEDREAM EXTREME DOLLZ VARSITY VICKY LIFE-SIZE LOVE DOLL', 

 is_in_stock after: 1
```

As you can see there has been no change to 'is_in_stock' and I can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

Thank you in advance for your help and patience

Comment: what you want to achieve you wanna turn 'is_in_stock' from 1 to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have used setStockData, instead, Try following:

```
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', (int) $inStock["NOTAVAILABLE"]);
```

or

```
$stockItem->setIsInStock((int)$inStock["NOTAVAILABLE"]);
```